# Change RecyclerView's Layout on orientation change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-orientation, gridlayoutmanager

I'm having `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. I'm displaying Single Column for landscape and Seven Columns for landscape. 
Using:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        recyclerViewCalender.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 7 : 1));
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

But the problem is the Layout used for portrait is not feasible for landscape.
So how can I change the layout of `RecyclerView` on configuration change.
Or is there any other solution for it??

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sufian Yes, Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for this, Pass one Flag to you `Adapter` which describe current orientation.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //Update the Flag here
    orientationLand = (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? true : false);
}
```

In your Adapter class:

```
@Override
public CalenderSessionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    //User Flag here to change layou
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(orientationLand ? R.layout.item_calender_session_land : R.layout.item_calender_session_port, null);
    return new CalenderSessionHolder(itemView);
}
```

Make sure you handle the View Id's properly to avoid Exceptions.

**Update:**

If you have two View Holder:

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        if (orientationLand)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_calender_session_land , parent, false);
            return new LandViewHolder(v);
        }
        else
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_calender_session_port, parent, false);
            return new PortViewHolder(v);
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

In Bind ViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    if (holder instanceof PortViewHolder)
    {
        PortViewHolder portHolder = (PortViewHolder) holder;
        //Initialize Views here for Port View
    } else if (holder instanceof LandViewHolder)
    {
        LandViewHolder landViewHolder = (LandViewHolder) holder;
        //Initialize Views here for Land View
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work fine but if someone has, like me, has made Activity undestroyable on rotation, two `ViewHolder`s need to be defined (one for port and other of land). Otherwise, some items will be following old orientation, and others will be of current orientation.

Comment: @Sufian Please check Updated answer for you problem..Hope it will work for you..:)

Comment: No, what I did was create separate ViewHolders for each orientation, like `ViewHolderPort` and `ViewHolderLand`. Then if the orientation was portrait, I would return different values for portrait and landscape from `getItemViewType()`. Doing this would force the adapter to create a new ViewHolder upon calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Your original solution was very close to what I actually did. :)

Comment: No, only layout is different.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something like this on onViewCreated. I check if the orientation is vertical or horizontal and then I give it a different view holder.

```
if (requireActivity().isOrientationLandscape()) setupRecyclerViewLand() else setupRecyclerViewPort()
```

then the view holders look like so.

```
    private fun setupRecyclerViewPort() {
    viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    viewAdapter =
        GenericItemListAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            object : GenericItemClickListener {
                override fun onPlayListClick(
                    play: Play,
                    adapterPosition: Int
                ) {
                    super.onPlayListClick(pratilipi, adapterPosition)
                    viewModel.episodePlaying.value = adapterPosition + 1
                    viewModel.init(play.playId)
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }

            }, GenericItemListAdapter.CardStyle.MOTION_COMIC
        )

    viewAdapter.let { recyclerView = binding.rvTaskList.with(viewManager, it) }
}

private fun setupRecyclerViewLand() {
    viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    viewAdapter =
        GenericItemListAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            object : GenericItemClickListener {
                override fun onPlayListClick(
                    play: Play,
                    adapterPosition: Int
                ) {
                    super.onPlayListClick(pratilipi, adapterPosition)
                    viewModel.episodePlaying.value = adapterPosition + 1
                    viewModel.init(play.playId)
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }

            }, GenericItemListAdapter.CardStyle.CAROUSEL
        )

    viewAdapter.let { recyclerView = binding.rvTaskList.with(viewManager, it) }
}
```

Thank you.